# Run PowerShell script with parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a PowerShell script that needs a path passed to it as parameter and surrounded with double quotation because path may be contains space. But my problem is when the path is root of drive for example `"E:\"` the passed parameter in the script converted to E:" (must be `E:\`) how to solve this problem? When I use single quotation the passed strings is `'E:\'` and contains the quotations!

Please help

my code sample:

```
in test.ps1
Write-Host ($args[0])


Result:
.\test.ps1 "E:\"
E:"

.\test.ps1 'E:\'
'E:\'

.\test.ps1 "'E:\'"
'E:\'

.\test.ps1 "E:\Test"
E:\test
```

I call the script from registry like this: powershell -File "test.ps1" "%V"

Comment: Why is it a problem that `E:\` is quoted? Can you provide a minimal powershell script to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Are you calling the script from an external program? \  is an escape in some environments.

Comment: I call the script from registry like this: powershell -File "test.ps1" "%V"

Comment: You need to escape the \ then with \\.

Comment: But registry expands "%V"

Comment: Have you tried reading [MS Docs on parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1)? Why are you using `$args[0]` instead of making the file be a function/cmdlet unto itself?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by changing `"%V"` to `'%V'` and in the script I use trim function to removes single quotations

```
$Arg0 = ($args[0])
$Path = $Arg0.trim("'")
```